# Persistent access from intent-shared URIs

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I can read an image via the Storage Access Framework mechanism and make access to the image persistent, so that I can present the same image after the app is restarted.

The app can receive image URIs via intents sent from other apps, such as Files or Gallery. They can be displayed when shared, but I've been unable to retain permission to access them after my app is restarted. I'd like to get persistent access to the intent-shared image.

I've tried requesting Persistability via the code below where intent  is the intent sent to my app by the sharing app.

```
Uri streamUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(streamUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION ) ;
```

Alas, the app crashes in the takePersistableUriPermission line as it receives the intent from the sharing app.  Without this line, the image is displayed, but the app crashes accessing the Uri when restarted. I need persistent access to the shared image.

Comment: How you are getting access to the Uri in the first place? Are you using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: If I understand the question correctly, the app is receiving the `Uri` via `ACTION_SEND`. Though the same issue would arise for `ACTION_VIEW`, etc.

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not possible. At most, maybe, if the `Uri` that you are given is from the Storage Access Framework, you can use `takePersistableUriPermission()`. But the `Uri` could easily be from something else, such as `FileProvider`, and for those you do not have an option for persistent access. If you need access to the content, make a copy to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`).

Comment: Proprietary apps, maybe pay-per-view, may not want their shares to be persistent. System apps should share persistent URI's as their content belongs to the user.

If the Storage Access Framework becomes the only way of accessing files, at least the system apps should provide persistent results.